# JQuery Validation PlugIn - submitHandler syntax

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using asp.net mvc 3 client validation. I am trying to do some stuff before any form is submitted. I found JQuery's validation has a submitHandler that seems to be what I am looking for but I am having problems with the syntax. T

I've tried the following but I get a syntax error.

```
 $(function () {
    submitHandler: function (form) {
      //my logic
      alert('here');
    }
  });
```

Thanks for any help!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call this as part of the [`.validate()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) options, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#formID").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      //my logic
      alert('here');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried that and for some reason didnt seem to work. However I tried:
 $("form").validate({ as I need to do this for all forms.

Comment: @B Z: The text inside the $("..") is a selector: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/.  You can change the selector to meet your needs--in Nick's example, the validate function is being called on the form with an id of formID.

Comment: @Andrew Whitaker - yeah, i got that, I think I know the issue. I was expecting submitHandler to happen before/during validation, not after. I can't find an event that happens before/during validation?

Comment: I will add my comment in a follow up question...thanks everyone