# JQuery Validation PlugIn - Event before/during validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, asp.net-mvc-3

Is there an event with the jquery validator plugin that I hook into? It is a bit of a follow up to these questions:

[CKEditor and ASP.Net MVC 3 RequiredAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491316/ckeditor-and-asp-net-mvc-3-requiredattribute)

[JQuery Validation PlugIn - submitHandler syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505366/jquery-validation-plugin-submithandler-syntax)

Basically I have a CKEditor that is not playing nice with jquery required validator. My thought was to hook into some event on validation so I can run this code:

```
var editor = $('#Body').ckeditorGet();
     editor.updateElement();
```

I looked into submitHandler, but that doesn't happen until AFTER validation takes place.

Also, this is on asp.net MVC 3 although don't think that matters...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and fixed it be adding code to the click handler of the input field like this

```
$('input[type=submit]').bind('click', function () {
    var editor = $('#Body').ckeditorGet();
    editor.updateElement();
});
```